# No rule to make target `AircraftAlgorithmPack'. Stop

Tags: qt

Обновился до MacOS 10.15, Xcode 11.1
При сборке проекта валится следующая ошибка:

```
error: No rule to make target `AircraftAlgorithmPack'.  Stop.
```

В выводе следующее:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `AircraftAlgorithmPack'.  Stop.
The platform SDK has been changed from version 10.14 to version 10.15.
This requires a fresh build. Please wipe the build directory completely,
including any .qmake.stash and .qmake.cache files generated by qmake.
/Users/arseniyspiridonov/Qt/5.13.1/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.mk:22: *** ^.  Stop.
18:17:03: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project AircraftAlgorithmPack (kit: Desktop Qt 5.13.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Понимаю, что это из-за несоответствия версии SDK, установленного на компьютере и версии SDK, установленного в настройках проекта (???). Но где поменять не понимаю

Comment: Полностью очистите проект и пересоберите

Comment: @AlexanderChernin пробовал